# Synchronous getFile() from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

The Firebase Reference docs [state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getFile(java.io.File)) that `getFile(File destinationFile)` is an asynchronous operation - much like the rest of Firebase operations.

My question is that how does one download files from multiple `StorageReference`s in a synchronous manner such that the next file begins to download only when the previous one has been downloaded?

The obvious solution is to store all the references in a list and call `getFile()` on the next reference from the previous `getFile()`'s `onSuccess()` method. This would make sure that the files are downloaded sequentially. However, I wanted to know if there's a better approach to this.

Also, how does Firebase manage multiple long-running asynchronous `getFile()` operations (video downloads, for example). Does it intelligently prioritise between concurrent download tasks based on some criteria, or do they occur simultaneously? And if so, then aren't concurrent downloads significantly slower?

Comment: There is no way to make asynchronous downloads synchronous without blocking the thread, which leads to "Application Not Responding". There is however likely a way to accomplish the synchronization between downloads. Something as simple as a counter could work: `if (downloadCompleteCount++ == totalFilesCount) { ...`.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen! I just have one more question - is `getActiveDownloadTasks()` on a StorageReference object activity independent? Can I call it on the same reference path, but in a different activity than the one in which the download began, and expect to get the appropriate download task?

Comment: Also, equally importantly - does does file download through `getFile()` continue even after the activity calling it has been destroyed?

Comment: Firebase Tasks always attempt to complete regardless of the state of any Activity that may have been active at the time they were started.  If you intend to continue where you left off, you'll need to use the Storage API to find that transfer and continue listening to it.

Comment: Thank you for your help @DougStevenson , so suppose that I begin a file download in a given Activity, and destroy the Activity before the task completes. Then, if I call `getActiveDownloadTasks()` on the same storage reference in a different activity, will the active download task be returned?

Comment: I believe that's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Alright, thank you once again!

Comment: For anyone else looking at this thread in the future...I don't think this is technically true, I do synchronous firestore/firebase retrievals, and as long as they're not blocking the UI thread for 5 seconds, they should be fine.